# sql server table joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table structure

```
EMPLOYEE (emp_id, emp_name)

ROLES (role_id, role_name)
```

`EMPLOYEE_ROLES (emp_id, role_id)` this is an association table for `EMPLOYEE` and `ROLE` relation

```
DOOR_GROUPS (group_id, group_name)
```

`DOOR_ACCESS_TO_ROLES (group_seq, role_seq)` this is an association table for `ROLES` and `DOOR_GROUPS`

```
DOORS (door_id, group_id, door_name)
```

Now I would like to get get all the `DOORS` for any specific `employee` by `employes` id or name. I am not sure how this can be achieved.

Comment: Have you tried any thing ??

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
 SELECT e.employeeId
    ,   D.door_id
    ,   D.door_name
    FROM Employees e
        JOIN employee_Roles ER ON e.emp_id = ER.emp_id
        JOIN Roles r ON ER.role_id = r.role_id
        JOIN door_access_To_Roles DAR ON DAR.Role_seq = r.role_Id -- Assumes this is the propper relation.
        JOIN Doors D ON D.group_id = DAR.group_seq  -- assumes again.
```

Comment: Thanks Jay! this seems be right and I am able to result that I want!